# Measures on infinite product of $[0,1]$?

Tags: measure-theory, geometric-measure-theory

What are the known measures defined on some sigma algebra on infinite product space of $[0,1]$ ? 
Is there any measure which is compatible with usual metric space structure of infinite product of $[0,1]$ ? Are these measures are significant?

Please refer to some good source to know details about this topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can construct useful measures on any product of $[0,1]$, even uncountable products. Real and Abstract Analysis by Hewitt and Stromberg has such a  construction. If $X_i$ is a sequence of indpendent random variables with uniform distributuion on $[0,1]$ then their joint distribution is a product measure on $[0,1]^{\infty}$. This measure is defined on the Borel sigma algebra for the metric $d$ defined by $d((x_n),(y_n))=\sum_n 2^{-n}\frac {|x_n-y_n|} {1+|x_n-y_n|}$. Such measures are very important in Probability Theory.